# Show that the partial derivatives exist at (0,0)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Consider the function
>   $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x^2+y^2)\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)&\text{if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
>   Show that the partial derivatives $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist.

What they are asking here?

Comment: Please, if you must post a picture, please ensure it is the right way up. Better, avoid pictures and write in MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They want you to show that $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist.

In particular
$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = f_x(0,0)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=f_y(0,0)$ exist.